# Remove Script From Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe, tinymce

This is a reformulation of my previous question.

I have an embedded tweet in a tinymce iframe. All embedded tweets come with a script that displays and formats the tweet so that it looks like a tweet. 
[image]

This is all good in the Iframe, but when I submit, I do NOT want to save the script formated text. I need the original pasted text in its original form:

```
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>LIVE: From Cairo, 
<a href="https://twitter.com/sharifkouddous">@sharifkouddous</a> 
reports on the ban of pro-democracy group, April 6 movement 
<a href="http://t.co/Xup8cdtVv9">http://t.co/Xup8cdtVv9</a> 
<a href="http://t.co/yfb3oIxRXU">pic.twitter.com/yfb3oIxRXU</a>
</p>&mdash; Democracy Now! (@democracynow) 
<a href="https://twitter.com/democracynow/statuses/461486533715836928">
April 30, 2014</a></blockquote>
<script id="remove" async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So what I've accomplished so far is to assign an id of "remove" (see above) to the script tag. Now I need to reach inside the iFrame and remove it before submitting.

Here's my html:

```
<form id="my_form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="editor_result.php">
<h3>Title of section: <input id="title" class="textbox" type="text" size="60" name="title" maxlength="65"  spellcheck="true"></h3>
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; font-size:80%">65 characters max...</p>
<textarea id="elm1" name="area"></textarea>
```

my js for this is:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#elm1_ifr').contents().find('body #remove').remove(); 
        $('#my_form').submit(); 
});
```

My problem is 2 fold:

- Get to iframe and remove #remove. It doesn't work however. I can remove a div etc... but not a script. Why?
- Submit form. I've disabled the submit button, but now the form doesn't want to submit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Removing the script tag won't help, it's already been executed so the HTML has been changed permanently.

Comment: Darn it... I had just figured it out. Thank you.